# How to write down an arbitrary vector as a linear combination of some given vectors?

Tags: vectors

> Write down an arbitrary vector
> $(a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4) ∈  \mathbb R^4$ as a linear combination of the vectors $u_1 = (1, 1, 1, 1), u_2 = (0, 1, 1, 1), u_3 = (0, 0, 1, 1)$ and $u_4 = (0, 0, 0, 1).$

Can I just do $\begin{pmatrix}a_1\\ a_2\\ a_3\\ a_4\end{pmatrix}=p\cdot u_1\:+\:q\cdot u_2\:+\:r\cdot u_3+s\cdot u_4$? What is the question trying to highlight with all those ones?

Comment: You have to find k,b,c,d explicitly in terms of the $a_i's$.

Comment: @ArcticChar Hmm, how can I do that? Using gaussian elimination?

Comment: Dispose the given coordinates as column vectors of a $4 \times 4$ matrix $A$, invert it by any method and apply $A^{-1}$ to the given vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Notice that $e_{1} = u_{1} - u_{2}$, $e_{2} = u_{2} - u_{3}$, $e_{3} = u_{3} - u_{4}$ and $e_{4} = u_{4}$.

Then you can express the given vector as the following linear combination:
\begin{align*}
(a_{1},a_{2},a_{3},a_{4}) = a_{1}e_{1} + a_{2}e_{2} + a_{3}e_{3} + a_{4}e_{4}
\end{align*}

Now it remains to make the corresponding substitutions.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Hi, how did you get your e1 and other es?

Comment: I denote $\{e_{1},e_{2},e_{3},e_{4}\}$ as the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^{4}$. More precisely, $e_{1} = (1,0,0,0)$, $e_{2} = (0,1,0,0)$, $e_{3} = (0,0,1,0)$ and $e_{4} = (0,0,0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

> > Write down an arbitrary vector
> > $(a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4) ∈  \mathbb R^4$ as a linear combination of the vectors $u_1 = (1, 1, 1, 1), u_2 = (0, 1, 1, 1), u_3 = (0, 0, 1, 1)$ and $u_4 = (0, 0, 0, 1).$
>
> Can I just do $\begin{pmatrix}a_1\\ a_2\\ a_3\\ a_4\end{pmatrix}=p\cdot u_1\:+\:q\cdot u_2\:+\:r\cdot u_3+s\cdot u_4$?

Yes, exactly: solve $\begin{pmatrix} 
1&0&0&0\\
1&1&0&0\\
1&1&1&0\\
1&1&1&1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
p\\
q\\
r\\
s
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1\\
a_2\\
a_3\\
a_4
\end{pmatrix}$ for $p,q,r,s$ in terms of $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4.$

> \begin{align} \begin{pmatrix}p\\q\\r\\s\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a_1\\-a_1+a_2\\-a_2+a_3\\-a_3+a_4\end{pmatrix} \end{align}